# Large dataset on Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, graph, dataset, sigma.js

I'm currently working on a project using sigma.js where I need to show a large number of nodes and edges (~10000 to ~100000 of each one) stored in a JSON file. But the library is getting laggy when I load the JSON, on each refresh and also when it shows me the graph it doesn't space the nodes. I was wondering if someone knows how to represent this kind of dataset fine.

Comment: related but incomplete: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/239

Comment: You're asking an awful lot of a JS library. You're asking about graph layout (itself an active area of research) and performance optimization together, and these are different kinds of concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest i am on the same issue if it can helps, i think the book example of Gephi.org tutorial is still the best.

For the moment i am on including sigmaJS from cloudflare but i don't have any proposition for this.

Something like you replace  the library with a link to cloudflare like the one used for phaser.io explained in it git repository or even tweenJS use the same way (it's the way of web devs see #indiedev #indiegamedev on twitter, it helps)

```
<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thefailtheory/L45ue3er/

Comment: Finnally I apply ForceAtlas2 algorithm to order the nodes and show them better. For more than ~60000 nodes it delays a little, but I think its the better solution I have found.

Comment: nice to see an issue for this

Answer (score 0):

The threejs random particle visualization performs really well with 20K points.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_random

Will be a bit of work to repurpose for network display but the upside is you can leverage GPU for rendering.